# concatenating two columns from oracle apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 2 columns from oracle apex to fill out one of the column. `P3_ID` contains text data like 09842 and `P3_Type` also contains data like 04214. I am trying to concatenate `P3_ID +'.'+P3_Type` (09842.04214) to put it into `p3_total`. So I add default value into P3_total to

```
select concat('P3_ID'+'.'+'P3_Type') from dual;
```

but It doesn't work for me. Does anyone have an idea to make p3_total to work?

Comment: Answer is fine, but it looks like you're using javascript syntax within Oracle SQL. Concat function would be more like concat(id, type) as joined_col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Assuming this is a computation assigned to P3, try

```
:P3_ID ||  '.' || :P3_Type
```

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03022) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm).